# Procedure to perform a web search (Bing) in Office 2013 task pane app

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, office-2013, office-app

I am trying to make an office 2013 task pane app where it is required to make a web search and display the result in the task pane.
Please explain the processes involved.
There is not much given in MSDN.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219429.aspx  This explains the process in detail.  The process is slightly different depending on which office app you're building for.  You can do task panes in... Excel, Word, Project and PowerPoint.

Here is a link to tutorials and samples... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142152.